# Create Check constraint Oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints

I'm trying to create a check constraint which enforces a rule across two columns but I'm getting this error :

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator.

I can't see which relational operator is wrong in my statement. Any help please ?

```
alter table "TRANSACTION" add constraint "CHECK_TRANSACTIONREFERENCE" check 
    ("REFERENCE" case when TRANSACTION_MEAN=2 then 
          (case when 'Reference' is not null then 1 else 0 end) 
    else 
          1 
    end = 1)
```

Comment: Looks ok, but 'Reference' should be replaced with "Reference", I think.

Comment: I checked with "Reference" but still the same error.

Comment: What are you trying to express?  What is `REFERENCE`?  Is it a column name?  That first part `"REFERENCE" case ...` is invalid syntax.  Not sure what you're trying to do.  Also, `case when 'Reference' is not null` will always evaluate to true because you are checking the string literal `'Reference'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the business rule you want to enforce is

> REFERENCE must be populated if TRANSACTION_MEAN equals `2`

So why not just code that?

```
alter table "TRANSACTION" 
    add constraint "CHECK_TRANSACTIONREFERENCE" 
    check (
             ( TRANSACTION_MEAN = 2 and Reference is not null)
       or TRANSACTION_MEAN != 2)
/
```